# Force snakemake to run python2 in a rule without --use-conda

Tags: python, snakemake

### Problem:

From within snakemake (python3), I am running some software written in python2. Snakemake runs the software using python3, ignoring the shebang on the file invoking python2. This is someone else's software, so I don't want to bother rewriting it all to work in python3.

### Question:

How do I force snakemake to run the python version in the shebang of an external script, rather than the python version in the current env?

### Caveats:

I know that snakemake allows the user to force a specific environment with `--use-conda`, and calling a python2 environment. However, I don't want to do this, as the resulting script will be less portable.

### What I have tried:

I have tried prepending the external python scripts with `#!/usr/bin/env python2` or `#!/usr/bin/python2`, and each time the scripts failed because Snakemake ran them with python3 instead of python2. Other programs with either of these shebangs runs in python2 when I invoke the script from the shell, outside of snakemake.

### Example:

This is the snakefile:

```
#snakefile
rule all:
    input:
        my_output.txt
rule foo:
    output:
        txt = my_output.txt
    shell:
        """
        external_program.py > {output.txt}
        """
```

This is `external_program.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

print "this will work in python2, but not python3"
```

Answer (score 1):

I really think you should solve this by using conda environments. I think your current approach is the "less portable" one. So I decided to give two answers in this question, one with, and one without, conda> In the hope that I would convince you to use the conda approach :).

### without conda

If python 2 is installed on your computer, then you can probably invoke it with either `python2` or `/usr/bin/python2`

```
rule foo:
    output:
        txt = my_output.txt
    shell:
        """
        python2 external_program.py > {output.txt}
        """
```

### with conda

Solving this with conda would require us making a environment.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  - python=2.7
```

and now we have to refer to this environment like so:

```
rule foo:
    output:
        txt = my_output.txt
    conda: "environment.yaml"
    shell:
        """
        python2 external_program.py > {output.txt}
        """
```

and use the `--use-conda` flag with snakemake.